# What does symbols like '♠' mean in a google sheets formula?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

So I found this excellent formula to transpose a table in google sheets, but I don't underestand what these symbols stand for '♠', '♦'.

This is the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Country", "Date", "CM1"; 
 QUERY(ESPACIOS(SPLIT(TRANSPONER(SPLIT(TRANSPONER(QUERY(TRANSPONER(QUERY(TRANSPONER(
 SI(BP!D2:AM<>"", BP!A2:A&"♠"&BP!D1:AM1&"♠"&BP!D2:AM&"♦", )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠")), 
 "where Col1<>'' order by Col1")})
```

Comment: I think they just meant to be placeholders. The idea would be that no text holds these icons, so splitting these per these placeholders seem safe to do. I'm however no query guru and could be wrong =). However, they have nothing to do with Excel, hence I cleared those tags.

Comment: I concur with @JvdV - these appear to just be delimiting between Rows and Columns for the purposes of Concatenating and Splitting the values, and have been chosen as unusual characters that are **unlikely** to be in your cells - they could be swapped for anything else that you don't use, such as `"↔"` and `"↕"`, without issue.  *Assuming* that I am translating the Functions into English correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JvdV and @Chronocidal said these symbols are used in this specific formula as a placeholder to delimiting the Rows and Columns. And they have been chosen because is very unlikely that you will find in your actual values.